# Baggage charge price difference based on country of origin

Tags: luggage, fees-and-charges, united-airlines, delta-air-lines

I have noticed that when flights originate in the USA (With both Delta and United) that the initial baggage charge is $USD25.  But when taking flights from Canada back to the USA the baggage fee is $CA25.

Is there any explanation for the difference in baggage fees other than "because"?

**edit**

Currently $USD25 is $CA33 and $CA25 is $USD19, so there is a significant price difference that has nothing to do with exchange rates. (And 2 weeks ago when I did the same trip the exchange rate was even worse and the equivalent CA->USA price was $USD18)

Comment: Were you expecitong an accurate conversion to CAD, down to the last cent? If so, at which exchange rate? Is the price supposed to change daily?

Comment: @fkraiem The current conversion of $CA25 is $USD19 so its nothing to do with exchange rates.  If it was a conversion rate issue then the fee should be closer to $CA33

Comment: Isn't it bound to the currency of payment? How much would it cost if you'd pay with USD in both directions?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo See my edit

Comment: They are price points that consumers will tolerate. There's no further logic to it, it is not as though the price is related to the marginal cost of transporting the bag.

Comment: Because they'd rather not change their prices every day depending on the latest currency exchange rate. And they prefer to charge round amounts.

Comment: @JonathanReez yet they'll happily change ticket prices when the wind changes direction.

Comment: @PeterM they don't need to print the price of tickets anywhere except the online booking sites. Compare that with the number of places where baggage charges are detailed, many of them outside the company's control. Changing those every day would be a nightmare.

Comment: @JonathanReez There is nothing to stop the airlines quoting fees a specific currency.

Comment: @PeterM and then do conversions on the spot? Lots of people still pay in cash, so having an exact conversion (even rounded to the nearest dollar) would still cause issues.

Besides you'd have to visibly clarify the exchange rate and the fact that the quoted price list is in US dollars. Simply not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $25 USD and $25 CAD have different values is irrelevant.

The US bag bee is $25 USD and the Canadian bag fee is $25 CAD.  It's really no more complicated that than.  The airlines don't take into account exchange rates.

Note, this applies when and where you pay the fee.  If you book a cross-border itinerary and prepay the bag fee, you will pay both in your local currency, along with the ticket.

If you pay for the return at the airport, you are charged that fee in that local currency.

So, to the airline, there is no difference, those are just the two local fees.

Comment: I think that @calchas also has a point about price points.   Especially when the airline requests people to gate check bags for free - and hence effectively discounting the checked bag by $LocalCurrencyFee

Comment: @Peter M, yes.  The fact that both are "25" is as much psychological as it is based on cost.